# Java Custom String Division into Dynamic Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, dynamic, division

I have a string which I have to divide according to a preset length array and then the substrings would go into a dynamic array.

Example:

S = 101010101011001100

Pass 1: Array = ("10101010", "11001100")

Pass 2: Array = ("1010", "1010", "1100", "1100")

Pass 3: Array = ("10", "10", "10", "10", "11", "00", "11", "00")
and so on....

I have tried with split(), vector, substring, etc. It hasnt given me the desired result.

Since the size of the array is also increasing with each pass with the substrings increasing similarly, I am having trouble understanding the actual division being done in the code. If someone can help me understand how to go about it, it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the "preset length array" look like?

Comment: *I am having trouble understanding the actual division being done in the code.* Can you post this code? We can help you understand it if we see it ourselves.

Comment: The preset array length is something like this:
length = {512,256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2}

Comment: CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc i havent been able to complete the code yet. So cant really post it. just tried the division with the methods mentioned

Comment: So, you're dividing every string in an array in half, then putting the results into a new array? Seems pretty straightforward, where are you having the first problem?

Comment: DaaaahWhoosh the icky part is that i am having to get the input from an unknown file which might contain any number of bits of data. Then I'm having to block them into substrings of 512 max. now the thing which i am worried about is that after dividing the bits, the last remainder bits might be anything within 0-512 in length. how do i divide according to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
public static void divideAndPrint(String... strs) {
     String[] array = new String[strs.length*2];
     for(int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        array[i*2] = strs[i].substring(0,strs[i].length()/2);
        array[i*2+1] = strs[i].substring(strs[i].length()/2);
     }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
     if (array[0].length() > 1)
         divideAndPrint(array);
}

divideAndPrint("1010101010110011");
```

prints

```
[10101010, 10110011]
[1010, 1010, 1011, 0011]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 00, 11]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Bahahahahaha!  If it's homework, recursion will give him a "copied from the internet 0". Cruel answer!

Comment: @Kieveli I try to give an answer they would never though of themselves. ;)Also I don't handle strings which are not a power of 2 in length.

Comment: thanks a lot Peter for the snippet but it threw a huge list of errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it compiles and runs for me.  Are you creating a class with a main method it put these pieces of code into?

Comment: of course!
class DivideAndPrint{

 public static void main(String ar[]){

  DivideAndPrint dap = new DivideAndPrint();
  dap.divideAndPrint("1010101011001100");
 }

 public static void divideAndPrint(String strs) {

      String[] array = new String[strs.length()*2];
          for(int i = 0; i < strs.length(); i++) {
         array[i*2] = strs[i].substring(0,strs[i].length()/2);
         array[i*2+1] = strs[i].substring(strs[i].length()/2);
     }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
          if (array[0].length() > 1)
            divideAndPrint(array);
 }
}

Comment: @CrazyCoder your main doesn't need to create an object, the method is `static`

Comment: These are the errors are i am getting Peter:
DivideAndPrint.java:12: error: array required, but String found
                array[i*2] = strs[i].substring(0,strs[i].length()/2);

Answer (score 0):

To go about it, first put your input 'S' into a single element array:

```
Input Array = { "101010101011001100" }
```

Now what you want to do, is loop over your input length array.  Then check to see if the first element in the array is shorter than the current length value, then do the following:

- Create a new array
- for each element in the old array,

  - Split into the length value size by using strValue.substring()
  - Add each piece into your new array
- replace the old array with the new array
- print out the values of the array to show it's working

By doing that to each iteration, you should end up with a result you're looking for.

Now this might not work too well if the input string length isn't an exact match to the input array length, or if the input array length isn't in decreasing order.  Watch for those edge cases if they matter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it did help Kieveli but the icky part is that i am having to get the input from an unknown file which might contain any number of bits of data. Then I'm having to block them into substrings of 512 max. now the thing which i am worried about is that after dividing the bits, the last remainder bits might be anything within 0-512 in length. how do i divide according to them?

Comment: I'd end the array in the rest of the data - ie, put 512 characters at the start of the array, and every element until you only have what's left.  The last element may not need to be split, but simply added on during the next iteration.